# TradingView. Pine-Script: plotshape above the previous bar and not current

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

**Objective:** Plot a downarrow above the candle if it's low is higher than the ema 5
**Issue:** It's plotting it on current candle whereas the satisfied condition is on [1] so it should be on [1]
**MyScript: **

```
//EMA5 alert
//@version=5
indicator("EMA 5 Alert", overlay=true)

// Calculate 5-period EMA
ema_5 = ta.ema(close, 5)

// Check if previous candle's low is higher than EMA 5
prev_low = low[1]
ema_5_prev = ta.ema(close, 5)[1]
condition = prev_low > ema_5_prev

// Plot shape and send alert if condition is true
plotshape(condition, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, size=size.auto, text="5",textcolor=color.red)
alertcondition(condition, title="EMA 5 Detected", message="Previous candle didn't touch EMA5")


// Plot EMA 5
plot(ema_5, color=color.rgb(66, 239, 245), linewidth=2)



plot(close)
```

**Output screenshot and mark what is desired:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUcKA.png)

I tried searching the official documentation and googled but couldn't find the exact same example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That blue line is the closing price. The last line of you indicator you have

```
plot(close)
```

Just delete that.

You are checking the previous bar to see if your condition is met so it will only be true on the next bar, which is where your arrow is plotting. If that's what you want you can use the offset parameter in the plotshape set to "-1". So you need to do this:

```
plotshape(condition, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.auto, text="5",textcolor=color.red, offset = -1)
```

or if you want it to plot on the actual candle as it is happening you would do this

```
ema5 = ta.ema(close,5)
condition = low > ema5

plotshape(condition, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.auto, text="5",textcolor=color.red)
```

Comment: Bingo! Precise, this is probably the fastest accurate response I've ever received... Thanks so much. Any possibility to connect directly? I may have a requirements for one or two scripts...

Comment: No problem and absolutely. You can message me on TradingView if you want. amphibiantrading is my name on there

Comment: Alright, will ping you tomorrow sometime and we fix a mutually convenient time for the chat